# два INNER JOIN в 1 запросе

Tags: phpmyadmin

У меня есть 3 таблицы, в 1 у меня вся информация про работника, а во второй про клиента, в 3 таблицу нужно имя работника и клиента через id.

Пример одного inner join[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат 1-го запроса[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда делаю идентично 2 inner join получается ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто подскажет как решить проблему?

Comment: А причём тут JOIN если говорит что таблица такая не существует?

Comment: имя таблицы введено правильно, но ошибка все-равно почему-то в имени

Comment: а может в БД другая буква "c" ? %)

Comment: да, вы были правы, как же неловко получилось ахахаха. P.S будьте внимательны

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в том что в бд таблица `clients` имела русскую букву с в названии, а запрос работает)